# Xcode 9.4 crash when create a build file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.4

When I am going to create a build for sharing in team at that time xcode going to crash
Following step are done for create a build:

> 1. Create a archive file
> 2. then click on export button
> 3. Select development from option
> 4. Select automatically managing signing

then I click on next button at that time Xcode is crashing.

Comment: I just tried to export one of my project using Xcode 9.4.1 but it seems fine, if you are using xcode in full screen mode try to exit full screen first, check how much ram is available in your mac, try to close everything else before archiving. See if it helps

Comment: when i am going with other option like validate or export to app store it work perfectly but in developement option it going to crashing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I has the same issue, but it turned out I had to agree to the updated user agreement in the developer portal.